# hasManyThrough laravel with logical operators

Tags: laravel

I am creating a chat system.
The chats are always for 2 people.
I have created the system with 2 tables:

**CONVERSATIONS TABLE**

```
Schema::create('conversations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_me');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_you');

            $table->foreign('id_me')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('id_you')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**MESSAGES TABLE**

```
Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('conversation_id');
            $table->text('msg');
            $table->boolean('read')->default(false);

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('conversation_id')->references('id')->on('conversations');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

But I need to bring all the messages of a user adding up all the conversations, something like this:

```
$user->messagesToMe;
```

**user relationship**

```
public function conversations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Conversation::class, 'id_me')->orWhere('id_you', $this->id);
    }

 public function messagesToMe()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Message::class,
            Conversation::class,
            'id_you', 
        )->where('user_id','!=', Auth::user()->id);
    }
```

the problem is that by the nature of the system, the user will sometimes be in the id_me and sometimes in the id_you.

I have tried with logical operators but the relation does not accept it.

```
public function messagesToMe()
        {
            return $this->hasManyThrough(
                Message::class,
                Conversation::class,
                'id_you' || id_me, 
            )->where('user_id','!=', Auth::user()->id);
        }
```

Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no possibilities for logical operators, multiple keys, or closures on the hasManyThough relation.

But in order to solve your case you could also consider the following approach:

You need a conversation-relation on your Message Model:

```php
// in Message Model
public function conversation() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Conversation::class);
}
```

Having this relation you can retrieve all messages which belongs a users conversation:

```
$userId = Auth::user()->id;
$messagesToUser = Message::where("user_id", "<>", $userId)
    ->whereHas("conversation", function ($qry) use ($userId) {
        $qry->where("id_me", $userId)
            ->orwhere("id_me", $userId);
    })->get();
```

In case you need it to be accessible on your User instance you could solve it like this:

```php
// in User Model

public function messagesToMe()
{
    return Message::where("user_id", "<>", $this->id)
        ->whereHas("conversation", function ($qry) {
            $qry->where("id_me", $this->id)
                ->orwhere("id_me", $this->id);
        });
}

public function getMessagesToMeAttribute()
{
    return $this->messagesToMe()->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put logic operators there but I guess you could make an union of the results.

Try this.

```php
public function messagesToMe()
{
    $messagesInConversationsByMe = $this->hasManyThrough(
        Message::class,
        Conversation::class,
        'id_me'
    )->where('user_id','!=', Auth::user()->id);

    $messagesInConversationsByYou = $this->hasManyThrough(
        Message::class,
        Conversation::class,
        'id_you'
    )->where('user_id','!=', Auth::user()->id);

    return $messagesInConversationsByMe->union($messagesInConversationsByYou);
}
```

Even if it works, it's really not ideal.

Edit: If you only need the count of messages, maybe a `withCount()` could help.

```
User::query()
    ->withCount([
        'conversations as total_messages' => function ($conversations) {
            $conversations->join('messages', function ($join) {
                $join->on('messages.user_id', '=', 'conversations.id_me')
                     ->orOn('messages.user_id', '=', 'conversations.id_you');
            });
        }
    ])->... ->get();
```

or `loadCount()` on an existing User instance.

```php
$user->loadCount([
    'conversations as total_messages' => function ($conversations) {
        $conversations->join('messages', function ($join) {
            $join->on('messages.user_id', '=', 'conversations.id_me')
                 ->orOn('messages.user_id', '=', 'conversations.id_you');
        });
    }
]);

// get count
$user->total_messages;
```

`Auth::user()` counts as an User instance. You can call `Auth::user()->loadCount(...)` and then get the count with `Auth::user()->total_messages`

Comment: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns . I get this error. What would be the ideal way to do it? I don't really need to bring the whole collection. I just need to bring the total count of messages (number).

Comment: The would mean the relationship return different amount of columns for some reasn. Weird. I'm not sure about a "best way". Maybe a count? I'll edit it in